# Models associations not working on Waterline

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline, hapi.js

I am using the [Dogwater](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dogwater) package to integrate the Waterline ORM in a NodeJS project based on Hapi.

I cannot get to work a simple One to Many association (the underlying DB is Mongo).

The owner model looks like:

```
  identity: 'companies',
  tableName: 'companies',

  connection: 'viveatDashboard',
  schema: true,
  attributes: {
    _id: {
      type: 'string',
      primaryKey: true,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    apps: {
      collection: 'apps',
      via: 'companyId'
    },
    ... // more attributes here
    migrate: 'safe',
    autoCreatedAt: true,
    autoUpdatedAt: true,
```

The model with references to Companies looks like this:

```
  identity: 'apps',
  tableName: 'apps',

  connection: 'viveatDashboard',
  schema: true,

  _id: {
    type: 'string',
    primaryKey: true,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },

  companyId: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
    model: 'companies'
  },
  ... // more attributes here
  migrate: 'safe',
  autoCreatedAt: true,
  autoUpdatedAt: true,
```

When the code for the route handler runs:

```
...
Companies.find().populate('apps').exec(function(err, apps) {
  return reply(apps);
});
```

The apps property for the fetched records is an empty array (I made sure that there are actually apps with references to existing companies).

Comment: Try running `sails lift --silly` and triggering the handler. The log should provide some extra info that's useful for debugging

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was that if the `_id` attribute is used as `primaryKey`, it must be then referenced in the model schema as `id` and not as `_id`.
Now the association works correctly.